# Copy file from addon to profile folder

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to copy a sqlite database from the data folder in my extension directory, to the profile folder, in order to use it.

So for now, I'm trying with that:

```
const {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
const {NetUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
const data = require('sdk/self').data;
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
       getService(Ci.nsIProperties).
       get("TmpD", Ci.nsIFile);
file.append("searchEngines.sqlite");
file.createUnique(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666);

// Then, we need an output stream to our output file.
var ostream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
ostream.init(file, -1, -1, 0);

// Finally, we need an input stream to take data from.
var iStreamData = NetUtil.ioService.newChannel(data.url("searchEngines.sqlite"), null, null).open();
let istream = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
istream.setData(iStreamData, iStreamData.length);

NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(aResult) {
  console.log(aResult); // return 0
})

console.log(FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["searchEngines.sqlite"]).exists()); // return false

let dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
```

The file seems to exist since the `console.log(file.exists())` return FALSE and is not populated (the `console.log(aResult)` return 0).

Where is my mistake, and is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You define `file` twice. I assume this is an error, and only the latter `TmpD` instance is to be considered?

Comment: Well, you're right, that's why the `file.exists()` return true.  
 It's an error after several copy/paste. Should I edit my question?

Comment: Please do edit your question with corrected code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides that it uses sync I/O (opening the channel with `.open` instead of `.asyncOpen`), the `NetUtil.asyncCopy` operation is still async, meaning the code

```
NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(aResult) {
  console.log(aResult); // return 0
})

console.log(FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["searchEngines.sqlite"]).exists()); // return false

let dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
```

will try to open the file **before** the copy likely finishes!
However, `file.exists()` will be likely true, because you already opened the file for writing. It's just that the file is still blank because the data copy isn't done (or even started) yet. (Actually, it is true, because you're checking `searchEngines.sqlite` in `ProfD` and not `TmpD`, but if you correct that the previous statement would apply).

You can only use the file when/after your callback to `.asyncCopy` is done, e.g.

```
NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(aResult) {
  console.log(aResult);
  console.log(FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["searchEngines.sqlite"]).exists()); // return false
  let dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
  // ...
});
```

PS: You might want to `.asyncOpen` the channel, then use `NetUtil.asyncFetch` and pass the resulting stream to `.asyncCopy` to be truly async for smallish files, since this caches the contents in memory first.

For large files you could create a variant of the `NetUtil.asyncFetch` implementation that feeds the `.outputStream` end directly to `NetUtils.asyncCopy`. That is a bit more complicated, so I won't be writing this up in detail until somebody is truly interested in this and ask the corresponding question.

*Edit*, so here is how I'd write it:

```
const data = require('sdk/self').data;

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

function copyDataURLToFile(url, file, callback) {
  NetUtil.asyncFetch(url, function(istream) {
    var ostream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].
                  createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
    ostream.init(file, -1, -1, Ci.nsIFileOutputStream.DEFER_OPEN);
    NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(result) {
      callback && callback(file, result);
    });
  });
}

var file = Services.dirsvc.get("TmpD", Ci.nsIFile);
file.append("searchEngines.sqlite");
copyDataURLToFile(data.url("searchEngine.sqlite"), file, function(file, result) {
  console.log(result);
  console.log(file.exists());
  console.log(file.fileSize);
});
```

Comment: After my correction, the `file.exists()` return false every time (if I fire it in the `asyncCopy(..)` or not).

Comment: My database size will not be up to 700ko, is that to be considered as a large file ?

Comment: Added test code that works for me (well, I did only copy a stub file, so I did not open the thing as an sqlite DB...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is working for me ! However, is that writing the file in the profile folder, or just in a temporary folder ? I just need to copy the database in the profile folder the first time the extension is loaded.

Comment: Feel free to modify the file path as you please. Right now it uses `TmpD`, because that is what your question used. However, please note that messing with search engines (the filename suggests this ;) might violate the [Add-on Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_guidelines) and get your add-on blocklisted.

Comment: Thank you nmaler, I don't think my addon violate the add-on guidelines, I will look closer to see if it's ok or not.

Comment: One more question :
Is the `copyDataURLToFile()` method async ?
I think yes, but is there a way to put all of that sync, it's not a really big deal, this method has to be executed on first launch of my module only.

Comment: Yes, it is async. And it should be async, in particular in startup code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OS.File it's much more straight forward.

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm")
var fromPath = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["searchEngines.sqlite"]).path;
var toPath = FileUtils.getFile("TmpD", ["searchEngines.sqlite"]).path;;
var promise = OS.File.copy(fromPath, toPath);
var dbConn;
promise.then(
    function(aStat) {
        alert('success will now open connection');
        dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(toPath);
    },
    function(aReason) {
        console.log('promise rejected', aReason);
        alert('copy failed, see console for details');
    }
);
```

Comment: Except that they read from a `self.data.url()` (second initialization of `file = `), which in all likelihood is a `resource:` URI pointing into an XPI (i.e. underlying `jar:` URI)...

Comment: Oh, to read from xpi you can use `NetUtils`, is it only if its not compressed? I thought it's zipped so you have to use `nsIZipReader` no?

Comment: You can use `jar:` channels to create channels into any JAR/ZIP/XPI... And once you have a channel, you can read from it and decompression is performed transparent and as-required.